# Polymer Dart core-style ref not resolved

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

When I pass parameters to a Polymer element the core-style *ref* does not get resolved.

Here is the child code:

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_style.html">

<core-style id="s1" unresolved> div { background: yellow; } </core-style>
<core-style id="s2" unresolved> div { background: pink;   } </core-style>

<polymer-element name='test-cell' attributes='s t' noscript>
  <template>
      <core-style ref="{{s}}"></core-style>
      <div>{{t}}</div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

As you can see, there are two core styles.

Here is the parent code. It takes a List and instantiates 'test-cell' with text and a style reference.

```
<polymer-element name='test-rows'>
  <template>
    <template repeat='{{ v in x }}'>
      <test-cell s={{v.s}} t={{v.t}}></test-cell>
    </template>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

In this simple example the Dart code is inline. Here it is:

```
  <script type='application/dart'>
    import  'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

    //======================================
    class Info {
      String  s, t;
      Info(this.s, this.t) {}
      }
    //======================================
    @CustomTag('test-rows')
    class TestRows extends PolymerElement {

      @observable List<Info> x = toObservable([]);

      //-----------------------------------
      TestRows.created() : super.created() {
        x.add(toObservable(new Info('s1', 'first' )));
        x.add(toObservable(new Info('s2', 'second')));
        }
      }
  </script>
```

In the generated HTML the text comes through OK but the core-style instances both have

```
ref="{{s}}"
```

and the styles are not applied. Can I force resolution of the style ref parameter by some alternative annotation? It is essentially a final/const.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

I think the problem is your `noscript` in your `test-cell` element.
Binding doesn't work in Dart with Polymer elements without a backing script (`noscript`) as far as I know.

I think in your case the `<test-cell>` element needs a field

```dart
@observable
var s;
```

to make this work.

#### Original

Your code doesn't show if you ever assign a value to `s`.

I doubt `toObservable` works on plain Dart objects. This is for lists and maps as far as I know.

The `Info` class should look like this and you don't need to use `toObservable()` with it.

```dart
  class Info extends Object with Observable {
    @observable
    String  s;

    @observable 
    String t;

    Info(this.s, this.t) {}
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. Concerning your first comment, a value is assigned to s via the Dart shorthand this.s. Sadly, your suggestion doesn't work. What is surprising is that {{v.t}} is extracted correctly and the value of t appears in the div. If I add {{s}} to the div, {{v.s}} is also extracted correctly and the value of s appears in the div. But no matter what I try, including your suggestion, the ref is assigned with the string "{{v.s}}" with no evaluation/interpolation.

Comment: Sorry I had a bit troubles interpreting your code. I'm not used to inline Dart script and I'm fighting with rather hard problems myself currently ;-). I think I understand your code now. To support just the code in your question you shouldn't need any observable at all. `@observable` is only necessary to update the view when the model changes **after** the view was initially bound. I'll have another look...

Comment: You were correct, adding a script makes a difference. As you suggested I then had to add the observable, plus an observable for t. Sadly, the handlebars are still not evaluated and I still get ref="{{s}}". Do you know if there's any way to get the "current evaluated value" of an expression? I also tried giving the software a hint by changing the class Info definition to "final String s" but that didn't work. Would it be possible to have the attribute change an internal var, detect the change in the var, and finally update the ref?

Comment: My brain refuses to cope with such a problem after such a day (it's 18:30 here). What you can try is `@PublishedProperty(reflect: true)` instead of `@observable` to make Polymer make the attribute value available in the DOM (not only internally). I can take a more closer look tomorrow.

Comment: Fixing the attribute via the 'attached' callback got the correct value into the 'ref'. But it had no effect. I cannot see a method to force the binding to re-evaluate. You can get the effect (via jsInterop) by digging out the core styles (context['CoreStyle']['list'][s]), extracting the cssText string and applying it as a style. But life isn't long enough ;-)

Comment: thanks for all the help. I hope it wasn't too much distraction from your day job. @PublishedProperty(reflect: true) did not seem to help. Have the Dart and/or Polymer people written any debugging tools so that we can see what is going on?